# download interrupted in OS X El Capitan, so can't install cordova

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I installed the virtual machine OS X el capitain, because I need only in Virtual Machine (I use VM WARE WORKSTATION 12x64)I wanted to install the apache cordova and android sdk
But faced with the following problems.

```
1. When I was downloading needed tools like git, nodejs and so on in Safari, the download speed on start is good, but in minute later, it freezes and stops.
2. when I downloaded android sdk, it was difficult to download a file from the SDK manager, I 100 times restarted it.
In log: ` download interrupted read time out`
With the help of God, i thousand times  turning off and turning on sdk manager
i spent day to  download 2gb.

it seems that any thing limits my internet,so Mac can't download
3. In general, when i became installation of Cordoba via terminal ,always stopping occures on this place.
(pic[![error install][1]][1])
```

http://s019.radikal.ru/i618/1610/6c/2f16f2d32c5a.jpg
And the problem is only  that traffic is normal at first,  then for some reason, it's reduced to zero (i don't download anymore).
Tell me

```
1. How to find out what stops traffic
2. well, or what is alternative install Cordova not using the terminal.
```

I use  VM Ware workstation 12 / I work with different OSes, and there internet is good, but only MAC is a exception. Even if all my OSes are switched off
 I can not understand what limited my traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that ssl was activated
i   disabled ssl and cordova installed

```
$ sudo npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

then my proxy

```
npm config set proxy "http://username:password@proxy_hostname:proxy_port"
```